# ORA-12505 + "network adapter could not establish the connection" on Oracle11g/VirtualBox

Tags: oracle11g, virtualbox

I have Oracle 11g installed locally on each of my virtualbox machines (working under Windows 7 64bit). Suddenty, after a simple reboot, the database on one of the 5 virtual machines doesn't want to connect anymore.
With SID connection I obtain ORA-12505 error, and with service name : "Network adapter could not establish the connection", in SqlDeveloper with both cases. If I try a connection with SqlPlus as sysdba, I obtain the connection but with "connected to an idle instance". Hence if I try to see, for example, the list of sessions and processes working, I have the error 01034 ("ORACLE not available"). I tried a lot of tricks but nothing works. Could it be a specific problem with virtual machines ?
Here what I tried :

1. the services (of my base and of the listener) are working (and I wait enough between relaunch and connection retry) ;
2. the files tnsnames.ora, listener.ora and sqlnet.ora seem correct (see below) ;
3. If I force localhost to be 127.0.0.1 in hosts file, I have the 12514 error ;
4. ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID are correctly set ;
5. It can't a priori be a memory problem (I even try to allow more memory to the specific VM which doesn't work) ;
6. If I force "startup" on sysdba session, the next requests obtain : ORA-03114 : not connected to ORACLE ;
7. It's not a priori a problem of system files size. In all cases, the not working database is not my biggest database among all my databases (and any file in oradata are bigger than in others VMs which have exactly the same configurations).

---

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle_32\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

---

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

---

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle_32\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle_32\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\oracle_32\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )


LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\oracle_32
```

---

Thank you to read !

---

Here the alert log for the first connection of this morning :

```
Fri Jun 23 11:08:13 2017
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on.
IMODE=BR
ILAT =167
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\ORACLE_32\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_2\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 1000
  sessions                 = 1524
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\ORACLE_32\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\ORACLE_32\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\oracle_32\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\ORACLE_32\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\ORACLE_32"
Fri Jun 23 11:08:20 2017
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=2160
Fri Jun 23 11:08:20 2017
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=2164 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=2168
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=2172
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=2176
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: option indiquée interdite !
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=2180
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=2184
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=2188
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=2192
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=2196
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=2200
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=2204
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=2208
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=2212
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
Fri Jun 23 11:08:21 2017
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=2216
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\oracle_32
Fri Jun 23 11:08:22 2017
alter database mount exclusive
Successful mount of redo thread 1, with mount id 1475182246
Database mounted in Exclusive Mode
Lost write protection disabled
Completed: alter database mount exclusive
alter database open
Fri Jun 23 11:08:31 2017
Errors in file c:\oracle_32\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_lgwr_2196.trc:
ORA-00338: log 3 of thread 1 is more recent than control file
ORA-00312: online log 3 thread 1: 'C:\ORACLE_32\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO03.LOG'
Errors in file c:\oracle_32\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_lgwr_2196.trc:
ORA-00338: log 3 of thread 1 is more recent than control file
ORA-00312: online log 3 thread 1: 'C:\ORACLE_32\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO03.LOG'
Errors in file c:\oracle_32\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ora_2232.trc:
ORA-00338: fichier journal 1 du thread  plus recent que le fichier de controle
ORA-00312: journal en ligne 3 thread 1 : 'C:\ORACLE_32\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO03.LOG'
USER (ospid: 2232): terminating the instance due to error 338
Fri Jun 23 11:08:34 2017
Instance terminated by USER, pid = 2232`
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the alert log of the database? that could be a good place to start looking.
Also when logged as sysdba, did you try to start the database: startup ?

If yes, what is the error message if any?

Comment: (I added the alert log to my first message) The OSD-04500 error seems appear when Oracle 32bit is used on Windows 7 64bit, what's it my case, but I need it to compile Oracle with Qt and mingw32. And for the "terminating the instance due to error 338", it seems it's because the wrong control file is used. But, big problem : I can't do backup, because Oracle is inactive etc. etc. And when I force startup, I obtain : ORA-03114 : not connected to ORACLE...